# How to set checked for all selected checkboxes

Tags: select, checkbox

I have many checkboxes. I want when user clicks submit button and he hasn't filled all required fields, these checkboxes that he has checked, to be checked. My code is the following, but when form submit, only last checkbox is cheked.

```js
 function teachers_show(yes, no){
        $(".toggle, .all_teachers_show,  .student, .school,  .teacher_school, .teacher, .class, .teacher_class").hide();
          if (no)
              $('.all_teachers_show').show();
          else
              $('.all_teachers_show').hide();
          $(":radio").prop('checked',false);
          $(yes).prop('checked',true);
      }
```

```html
<?php
  
  echo validation_errors();
  echo "<div class='container' id='register_container'>";
  echo form_open('home/register');
echo "<table border = '0' >";
  echo "<tr><td><label>  Username:* </label></td><td>";
  $data=array(
    'name' => 'username',
    'class' => form_error('username') ? 'error' : '',
    'value' => set_value('username')
  );
  echo form_input($data);
  echo "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td><label> Password:* </label></td><td>";
  $data=array(
    'name' => 'password',
    'class' => form_error('password') ? 'error' : ''
  );
  echo form_password($data);
echo "<tr><td><label>  Choose role:* </label> </td><td>";
$selected_role = $this->input->post('role_id');  ?>
  <input type="radio" name="role_id" id="radio1" onclick="showHide(this, true)" value="1" 
  <?php echo '1' ==  $selected_role ? 'checked="checked"' : 
      '' ?>/>
      <?php  echo " Role 1"; ?>
      <input type="radio" name="role_id" id="radio2" onclick="showHide(this, true)" value="2" 
  <?php echo '2' ==  $selected_role ? 'checked="checked"' : 
      '' ?>/>
       <?php  echo " Role 2 "; ?>
      <input type="radio" name="role_id" id="radio5" onclick="teachers_show(this, true)" value="5" 
  <?php echo '5' ==  $selected_role ? 'checked="checked"' : 
      '' ?>/>
  <?php  echo " Role 3 "; 

  echo "</td></tr>";
 <?php
  echo "<tr class='all_teachers_show' style='display:none;'><td><label>  Teachers:*  </label></td><td>";
  ?>
 <table border='0'>
  <tr>
  <?php    
           $ind = 0;

           foreach ($all_teachers_show as $row) { 
           $ind++; 
?>
  <td>
  <?php $selected_teachers = $this->input->post('all_teachers_show[]');  echo $selected_teachers; ?>
  <input type="checkbox" id='all_teachers_show' <?php echo set_checkbox('all_teachers_show',$row->user_id); ?> name="all_teachers_show[]"
   value="<?= $row->user_id ?>" <?php if ( isset($selected_teachers[$row->user_id] )) 
    echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>><?= $row->first_name . ' ' . $row->last_name ?> <td>
      <?php 
      if($ind % 3 == 0)
       echo '</tr> <tr>';
} ?>
</table>
   <?php
   echo "</td></tr>";
  echo "</div>";
  echo "</table><br/>";
$data=array(
    "name" => 'mysubmit',
    'class' => 'btn btn-success ',
    'id' => 'reg',
    'value' => 'Register'
    
  );
  echo form_submit($data);
  ?>
  </form>
```

That's my whole code. These chechboxes are for Role 3 - radio button with id='radio5'.

How could it be my if: `<?php echo $selected_teachers == $row->user_id ? 'checked="checked"' : 
    '' ?>`
 `$selected_teachers` - it returns array and I compare it with `$row->user_id` 
How could be done that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php 
foreach ($all_teachers_show as $row)
{ 

    $userId = $row->user_id;
    $first_name = $row->first_name;
    $last_name = $row->last_name;
    $teacherSelected = ( isset($_POST[$userId]) ) ? true : false;

    ?>

        <td>
          <input 
                type="checkbox"
                class='all_teachers_show'  
                name="<?php echo $userId; ?>"
                <?php 
                    if ( $teacherSelected ) 
                        echo 'checked="checked"'; 
                ?>
                value="<?php echo $userId; ?>" 
            >
                <?php echo $first_name . ' ' . $last_name ?> 
        <td>
<?php
    }
```

Comment: I want if I check for example 10 of the checkboxes and I press Submit button - This is register form, and if I haven't filled username, password, not to have to check the checkboxes again - they shouls be checked

Comment: iv'e edited my answer to fix bugs in the code. you can use that

Comment: In this way, it doesn't check any checckbox - with isset. I have foreach and $row->user_id - is returned from query. I want for each checkbox to see if it is selected and if it is, when submit form, to be still checked.

Comment: edited it again. i'm assuming that `$this->input->post($userId)` will return null if `$_POST[$userId]` isn't set

Comment: Now, all checkboxes are checked .. :( I don't know how to make this if - if the value you have chosen is equal to value of dropdown, checked=checked..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77542/discussion-between-captain-crunch-and-girl89).